# 37 Signals Style Lightbox | How to do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, 37-signals

Does anyone know how 37 Signals built the pop ups for image previews that are now in basecamp? I really like how quickly they load and the fact that the whole page doesn't get "light-boxed" and there is a minimal border It's very snappy. You can see this effect on the marketing page for campfire:

http://campfirenow.com/?source=37signals+home

Just click one of the images below plans and pricing.

Is this custom javascript? Are they using a certain javascript library? Anyone know?

Comment: Try viewing the source. I'd do it myself to try to determine what lightbox is in use, but my iPhone browser isn't good at stuff like that. It looks familiar, though - it may be a jquery lightbox plugin styled to look different from the default.

Comment: Hey Lee, did my answer help you find the solution you were after? Perhaps you could accept my answer if so. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at:

http://campfirenow.com/sprockets.js

and search for `setupZoom()`

The method being used for the clicks is `zoomClick()`

It looks like they're using [FancyZoom](http://www.cabel.name/2008/02/fancyzoom-10.html) to do the work and this is being combined with the [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) Javascript Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Cool Thanks!

I also found this:
http://www.highslide.com/

It's a really similar effect that doesn't require Prototype.